# Paypal IPN unable to change currency type from USD to GBP

Tags: php, forms, paypal, paypal-ipn

Here's the form...

```
<form method="post" name="paypal_form" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="email_address"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="URL"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="URL"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="URL"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="item_name"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="30.00"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="mc_currency" value="GBP"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Pay online now.">
</form>
```

Problem is it's always in USD, despite the mc_currency value and I've tried a whole bunch of permutations to no effect.  Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use currency_code

```
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
```